# Socket.IO multiple files server-side

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a nodejs backend and a react frontend. On nodejs I have socketio set up, on the client side I have the connection in the App component, and passed down using context. Now, using hooks, I can use the io variable globally and listen on client-side to events.

However, on server side, I have this IO variable also globally available, but how to use this on multiple pages?
I have this code in server.ts:

```
const io = //initialize io
io.on('connection', (socket: any) => {
    console.log('a user connected', socket.handshake.query);

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });

    io.on('test', console.log);
});
```

But, in a different file, I have to initialize my connection using `io.on()`again. How to work around this? I have a file called foo.controller.ts which has some actions around foo. In this file I want to listen all events related to foo.

Answer (score 4):

Create new file ex. `socket.instance.js`, then create class to handle all socket's logic, like storing sockets list or something (it's up to you what you need);

Here is example of `socket.instance.js`:

```js
const Subject = require('rxjs').Subject;
class SocketInstance {
  io = require('socket.io')();
  sockets = new Set();
  newSocket = new Subject();

  constructor() {
    this.io.listen(process.env.PORT);

    this.io.on('connect', socket => {
      this.sockets.add(socket);

      this.handleNewSocket(socket);

      socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        this.sockets.delete(socket);
      });

      this.newSocket.next(socket);
    });
  }

  handleNewSocket(socket) {
    // logic here
  }
}

const socketInstance = new SocketInstance();

module.exports = {socketInstance}
```

Then in any other file you can access to this instance like this:

```js
// anotherServerFile.js
const socketInstance = require('./socket.instance').socketInstance;

socketInstance.io.emit('hello');

// yetAnotherFile.js
const socketInstance = require('./socket.instance').socketInstance;
socketInstance.newSocket.subscribe(socket => {
    socket.on('test', console.log);
});
```

**It's only basic example how to share your socket server instance between any other classes/files in your code. Everything depends on your needs**

And on frontend situation is somewhat similar

Comment: That doesnt solve my issue I think. This way I still pass down io, not socket. For example, how to define socket.on(‘bar’, console.log) in file bar.ts? To have the socket variable, i still need to rewrite io.on(connection)

Comment: I updated example for your needs. I just add `Subject` from `rxjs` library, you can replace it even with simple event emitter. But now you have access to new connected `socket` in every file you want, all you need to do is subscribe `newSocket`

Comment: Hi, thanks. I think I just don't understand how it works to start with. Is socket a "per user variable"? I have my server.ts file which defines the on-connect events. The IO variable on client side can be used to listen to server events `io.on('test', console.log)` but on the server this IO variable is not used for listening to custom events, but the SOCKET variable in the on-connect callback is. SO, if I have 100 custom events I want to listen to, I need to specify them all in 1 file and 1 callback function, right?. How would you do it if you have a lot of custom events?

Comment: On server side you have multiple `socket` variables, because every client is a single object. On your server side logic, you can handle every socket as you want because some sockets needs to listen at `bar` event and some of them not - it's up to your needs. `if I have 100 custom events I want to listen to, I need to specify them all in 1 file and 1 callback function, right?` - no you don't have to, you can use this example with `newSocket` and add this custom events in the other files

Comment: But better use `TypeScript` for whole backend, with this package https://github.com/typestack/socket-controllers It's what you need, you han simply have access to events across all files using decorators

Comment: Sorry, you're confusing me like crazy :( Can you maybe provide an example without the rxjs lib? Maybe this library is confusing me.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more? As you bring in the concept of observables which I dont master/understand. Tried looking into it but cannot understand the concept.